# Create map in Java for HTML

Tags: java, html, xpath, maps

I have the following HTML I am working with:

```
<table class="detailTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="detailTitle" align="top">
        <h3>Credit Limit:</h3>
        <h3>Current Balance:</h3>
        <h3>Pending Balance:</h3>
        <h3>Available Credit:</h3>
      </td>
      <td align="top">
        <p>$677.77</p>
        <p>$7.77</p>
        <p>$7.77</p>
        <p>$677.77</p>
      </td>
      <td class="detailTitle">
        <h3>Last Statement Date:</h3>
        <h4>Payment Address</h4>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>   05/19/2015  </p>
        <p class="attribution">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to create a map in Java that checks the position of a certain `<h3>` like `Credit Limit` and then uses the position to get it's value from the corresponding `<p>`. The tricky part is— the HTML content is dynamic. So, it can come up differently and the map should still work. Example:

```
<table class="detailTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="detailTitle" align="top">
        <h3>Current Balance:</h3>
        <h3>Pending Balance:</h3>
        <h3>Available Credit:</h3>
      </td>
      <td align="top">
        <p>$7.77</p>
        <p>$7.77</p>
        <p>$677.77</p>
      </td>
      <td class="detailTitle">
        <h3>Last Statement Date:</h3>
        <h3>Credit Limit</h3>
        <h4>Payment Address</h4>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>   05/19/2015  </p>
        <p>$677.77</p>
        <p class="attribution">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Does anybody have any ideas how to do this? Really struggling with the map creation that can take care of changing HTML content. Any guidance or help is greatly appreciated :)

NOTE: I cannot use XPath 2.0 or functions like position() etc. So, I need to have some kind of workaround to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access XML content you can use a SAX or DOM parser to walk through it. I would prefer a SAX parser because it's fast and you can define callbacks for detected elements and stuff. In this callbacks you can build any map you need for the later compare.

In earlier projects I use Apache Xerces for problems like that. You should easy find examples how to use it.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But unfortunately I can't use xml. I have to create a map in java, that can correctly map the headers and their values irrespective of changing positions.